# Embedding windows Universal app inside another Universal app

Tags: angular, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I am developing an Angular2 app and I want to embed it inside Universal App container. 
Currently I see two options: 
1. Use Native Universal WebView to interact/load my Angular2 app
2. Export Angular2 as Universal solution, and embed it inside another Universal (which will be the controller/header of the embedded app)

Is this possible? What option is better?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking here. When you say you have "an angular2 app" do you mean a web app? Have you tried running it in a Webview? What about a Hosted Web App or a WinJS app? Have you looked at Cordova or Ionic as options? Why if you turn it into a UWP app would you want to embed that within another UWP app?

Comment: Hi @MattLacey, I currently have UWP app of a client. He wishes to add features to this app, and we wanted to make an angular2-web app embedded within UWP frame.
So, the UWP wrapper has a header (which should be able to get data from the embedded web-app etc.). the rest of the UWP is an empty container to put the web-app inside